# Silverstripe - Form with custom template shows wrong validation errors

Tags: validation, forms, silverstripe

I have the following custom form

```
$list = DataObject::get('AreaOfExpertise');
foreach ($list as $l) {
$source[$l->ID] = $l->Name;
}
$fields = new FieldSet(
new TextField('Customer'),
new TextField('ProjectName'),
new DateField('WinDate'),
new TextareaField('Details'),
new OptionsetField('AreaOfExpertiseID', 'Area Of Expertise', $source),
new TextField('ProjectValueLength'),
new TextField('DeliverTimeframe'),
new TextField('ProjectTeam'),
new TextField('Contact')
);
$actions = new FieldSet(
new FormAction('doSubmit', 'Submit')
);
$requiredFields = array(
'Customer',
'ProjectName',
'WinDate',
'Details',
'AreaOfExpertiseID',
'ProjectValueLength',
'DeliverTimeframe',
'ProjectTeam',
'Contact',
);
$validator = new RequiredFields($requiredFields);
$form = new Form($this, 'SubmissionForm', $fields, $actions, $validator);
$form->setTemplate('Forms/NewWinForm');
return $form;
```

and my template for this form is

```
<form $FormAttributes>
<% if Message %>
<p id="{$FormName}_error" class="message $MessageType">$Message</p>
<% else %>
<p id="{$FormName}_error" class="message $MessageType" style="display: none"></p>
<% end_if %>

<fieldset id="formContainer" class="clearfix NewWinForm">

<div id="Customer" class="row field text">
<label class="left" for="{$FormName}_Customer">Customer</label>
<div class="middleColumn">$dataFieldByName(Customer)</div>
</div>
<div id="ProjectName" class="row field text">
<label class="left" for="{$FormName}_ProjectName">Project name</label>
<div class="middleColumn">$dataFieldByName(ProjectName)</div>
</div>
<div id="WinDate" class="row field text">
<label class="left" for="{$FormName}_WinDate">Win date</label>
<div class="middleColumn">$dataFieldByName(WinDate)</div>
</div>
<div id="AreaOfExpertiseID" class="row field text">
<label class="left" for="{$FormName}_AreaOfExpertiseID">Area of expertise</label>
<div class="middleColumn">$dataFieldByName(AreaOfExpertiseID)</div>
</div>

<div id="Details" class="row field textarea">
<label class="left" for="{$FormName}_Details">Project details</label>
<div class="middleColumn">$dataFieldByName(Details)</div>
</div>
<div id="ProjectValueLength" class="row field text">
<label class="left" for="{$FormName}_ProjectValueLength">Project value/length</label>
<div class="middleColumn">$dataFieldByName(ProjectValueLength)</div>
</div>
<div id="DeliverTimeframe" class="row field text">
<label class="left" for="{$FormName}_DeliverTimeframe">Delivery timeframe</label>
<div class="middleColumn">$dataFieldByName(DeliverTimeframe)</div>
</div>
<div id="ProjectTeam" class="row field text">
<label class="left" for="{$FormName}_ProjectTeam">Project team</label>
<div class="middleColumn">$dataFieldByName(ProjectTeam)</div>
</div>
<div id="Contact" class="row field text">
<label class="left" for="{$FormName}_Contact">Contact</label>
<div class="middleColumn">$dataFieldByName(Contact)</div>
</div>
</fieldset>
<div class="Actions">
<% if Actions %>
<% control Actions %>$Field<% end_control %>
<% end_if %>
</div>
</form>
```

When I submit the form, instead of "*Please fill out "**Customer**", it is required*." message I get "*Please fill out "**this**", it is required*."

This is happening for all fields apart from **Details** field!

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? It's killing me...

Comment: If I remove `$form->setTemplate('Forms/NewWinForm');`, everything works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after some digging in `sapphire/javascript/Validator.js`, I found that the first class of the wrapper div must be `field` so I replaced this
`<div id="Customer" class="row field text">` with `<div id="Customer" class="field text row">` and everything works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This should be done by creating a form class and implementing the "forTemplate()" function. See [SilverStripe Forms](http://doc.silverstripe.org/sapphire/en/topics/forms).

Also, instead of creating the "AreaOfExpertise" source array the way you have, there's a convenience method, [toDropDownMap()](http://api.silverstripe.org/2.4/sapphire/model/DataObjectSet.html#methodtoDropDownMap), that does this for you.

```
$source = $list->toDropDownMap('ID', 'Name');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it didn't work. I still get **this** instead of the field name in the error messages. here is the form class I just created [link](http://pastebin.com/bPTfx77v)